# Android : Databinding, notifyPropertyChanged() not working?

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using Android's data binding library. I have my data object extending `BaseObservable`.

```
public static class SimpleData extends BaseObservable implements Serializable {
    private String text, subText;
    private SpannableString totalText;

    @Bindable
    public SpannableString getTotalText() {
      return totalText;
    }

    public void setTotalText(SpannableString totalText) {
      this.totalText = totalText;
      notifyPropertyChanged(BR.totalText);
    }
}
```

And my xml is binded as well

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/patient_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/patient_image"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:text="@{object.getTotalText()}"/>
```

The binding takes place for the initial values. But when I change the value using

```
object.setTotalText(someSpannableString);
```

the changes are not reflected in the text view. What could be the problem?

Comment: could you resolve your problem sir?

Comment: @mahdipishguy :No sir. The problem ain't resolved yet

Answer (score 9):

**Using field's name instead of getter.**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/patient_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/patient_image"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:text="@{object.totalText}"/>
```

Comment: seems incorrect, you should be using the `BR` class to identify the field _AND_ have both the setter and getter annotated with `@Bindable`

Answer (score 3):

Need to add `=` for two way data binding:

```
android:text="@={LoginViewModel.address}"
```

I forgot to add `=` so its didn't work. If you are using `EditText` then want two way data binding by base `BaseObservable` then you
need `@={LoginViewModel.address}` instead of `@{LoginViewModel.address}`.

Comment: This Worked on me Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. My binding would work the first time and then would not work the second time.

I had an identical setup to yours except I had put `@Bindable` on my setter and not my getter method.

Adding `@Bindable` to both my setter and getter fixed this issue for me.

> When I debugged the inner workers of the data binding library I
>   noticed that a method called request re-bind was not being called
>   because it did an operation to check if the field was updated or not
>   from the last value. My guess is you need the annotation on both
>   methods so that it can do this internal confirmation to check if it
>   needs to re-bind or not.

I'm not 100% if this is true or not, but having the annotation on both methods fixed my issue. Looking at the Data Binding library documentation I notice they just show the annotation on the getter.

You can try:

```
@Bindable
public SpannableString getTotalText() {
  return totalText;
}

@Bindable
public void setTotalText(SpannableString totalText) {
  this.totalText = totalText;
  notifyPropertyChanged(BR.totalText);
}
```

See if it resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define your `String` values as `public` not a `private`.
Also data binding detects getter and setter automatically, so just type `@{object.totalText}` as other already said.

I hope this Youtube Link will be helpful to you too.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6ejIx5xu-M

Answer (score -5):

Use `notifyChange()` instead of `notifyPropertyChanged(BR._)`.

Comment: please remove your comment, notifyPropertyChanged works for databinding